# Android - Cron String and Cron Job with Quartz

Tags: android, cron, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

I am working on a Android project that needs to run cron jobs by parsing cron strings.

I am using Quartz library. But I get exception below
Can you help me on this subject? You can also suggest another api or solution?

> 09-04 14:36:44.050    4907-4907/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.beans.Introspector
>               at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.setBeanProps(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1393)
>               at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:849)
>               at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1519)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve my problem in a different way that I use `CronExpression` class of Quartz in order to convert cron string to date. Then I use android `AlarmManager` to fulfill  my needs.